# Преобразование int в string

Tags: .net

Не могу вывести в текст-бокс число из переменной. Т.к. текст-бокс только строковые параметры воспринимает.

```
int z;
int x;
int y;
...тут некоторый код...
z = x + y;
textbox->Text = z;
```

> `Error 1 error C2664: 'void System::Windows::Forms::Control::Text::set(System::String ^)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'int' to 'System::String ^'`

Answer (score 2):

```
textbox->Text = z.ToString();
```

Так не работает?

Comment: Спасибо. Отлично работает.

Answer (score 1):

[Convert.ToString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.convert.tostring.aspx) - это по первому же результату google.

Если начинаете программировать на каком-то языке программирования, то и начните пользоваться поисковыми системами, а не по каждому пустяковому вопросу писать на форумы или в подобные места.

Comment: Спасибо за совет. Просто может не так запрос задавал в поисковиках, т.к. находил только форумы где преобразование было через библиотечные функции. Но был уверен что есть проще способ.